# Math.random error

Tags: javascript

When I run the following code this error occurs:

> Oops, try again. 
>   Did you use Math.random() to get a random number?

Using:

> declare a variable and make it equal to Math.random(), that variable will equal a number between 0 and 1

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock,paper or scissors ?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

console.log (computerChoice);

if (computerChoice < 0.29) {
    computerChoice = 'rock';
} else if (computerChoice > 0.30 && computerChoice < 0.60) {
    computerChoice = 'paper';
} else {
    computerChoice = 'scissors';
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: In what environment are you trying to execute the javascript? It works fine for me in firefox with firebug. A side note, your random alternatives are not evenly distributet. If this is not the intention, the distribution should be approximately in intervals of 0.33

Comment: That error message isn't even in your code. Please add a) more information, b) describe your expected behavior and c) describe the error in detail.

Comment: when i run this code its randomly choose rock . paper and scissors but this error also shows Oops, "try again. 
Did you use Math.random() to get a random number?"

Comment: The code seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/wHehk/ The `prompt` doesn't do anything. But if you have the console open, you should see the random number and "choice" selected.

Comment: problem is sovled   i appear to have an erroneous space here: Math.random ();. The checker will think that you didn't use Math.random() with it there!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking up something completely different and stumbled across this question.

The OP was referring to exercise 2.4 of Build Rock Paper Scissors on Codecademy.

I believe the code he was looking for was:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <0.34){
    computerChoice = "rock";
}else if(computerChoice <=0.67){
    computerChoice = "paper";
}else{
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var compare = function(choice1, choice2){
    if (choice1 == choice2){
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }
    if (choice1 == "rock"){
        if (choice2 == "paper"){
        return("paper wins");
    } else {
        return("rock wins");
    }
    }
    if (choice1 == "paper"){
        if (choice2 == "rock"){
        return("paper wins");
    } else {
        return("scissors wins");
    }
    }
    if (choice1 == "scissors"){
        if (choice2 == "rock"){
            return("rock wins");
        } else {
            return("scissors wins");
        }
    }
};
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
```

I'm sure the OP has long since found the answer to his lesson in the CC forum. But I thought I'd answer it in case anyone else doing the lesson, came here, saw the post and needed an answer.

Original Source of OP question I believe comes from:
[Link to Task](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/1#!/exercises/3)